# Select Wifi network component like app store one

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, iphone-privateapi

i want to add the component of selecting wifi network like in app store application .
have you any idea how to integrate it?
[image]
private methods are welcome!

Comment: do you want to add a fake screen for Wifi selection as you can't do it from apple documented api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly control the popup - it's a system function. However, if you set "Application uses Wi-Fi" to YES in your app's .plist, it will pop up when the user is not connected to the internet.

Comment: still a thing : that once the popup is shown , it does not appear another time (and this for other apps like app store).

there is a solution to enforce the call?

Comment: if user turns the phone off the popup reappears when he launchs the app after turning the phone on

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think Apple provides a way to do this. Like you said, this feature is absent from even Apple's own apps. I suppose if WiFi is needed, you can show a custom alert that says something like "Please connect to the internet", and the user should know to go to preferences and select a network.

Comment: yes, just a word: the pop up reappears when you lock your device.